# Writing a Webservice class for the WSDL that need to be shared with the third party

Tags: integration, wsdl

I have a requirement to create a class and generate a wsdl and 
share with the other party. The class should have the following in 
the first place when the other users consume my WSDL and when I make a request
I had to get the acknowledge. This is the first time I am writing a class for WSDL

Please share any links or shower your thoughts which could let me initate this task.

Thanks,
Suri.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure you want to create a custom API and it has to be SOAP then see e.g. [WebService Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services_methods.htm). There is a bit more detail in the "Apex Web Services" section of [Apex Web Services and Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts).

But generally JSON and REST patterns are easier for client's to use than SOAP. So if you have a choice you might consider the [Apex REST Annotations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotations_rest.htm) instead. Also see [Creating REST APIs using Apex REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST).